# AWS Lambda as a data service for other Lambdas

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-dynamodb, microservices

I'm modelling data in DynamoDB and the table relationships are getting complex,
so I created a Lambda for CRUD operations to avoid any direct access to the data by my other services and want it to serve as a data gateway.

Is that advisable?
What are some downsides to doing this?
Any alternatives?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This is fine, and quite frequently done. Other alternatives are using GarphQL like access via AppSync.

https://docs.aws.amazon.com/appsync/latest/devguide/graphql-overview.html